# How to build combinations of keys in places that are ordered

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have `keys` and `places`. I want to put the elements of `keys` in place of `places`, in every combination. Except the combinations should respect the ordering of the keys.

```
// I have this
let keys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let places = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

// I want all these arrays in an array
[0 1 2 3 4]
[0 1 2 3 5]
[0 1 2 3 6]
[0 1 2 3 7]
[0 1 2 3 8]
[0 1 2 4 5]
...
[0 2 5 7 8]
[0 2 6 7 8]
[0 3 4 5 6]
...
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 8]
[4, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I can't figure out what kind of for loop I have to construct. Or even with list comprehensions.

Because the places array's length can change.

Comment: Here's a previous answer with the Javascript for permutations. So it is the permutations of [false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469033/how-to-slow-down-the-output-of-a-list-using-settimeout-inside-of-js-function (scroll to the end for my answer)

Comment: Please add the commas in the arrays :) ocd kicking

Comment: Here's a link to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xc8t0b9s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @QuentinUK , answer it worked like this:

```
console.log(combinations([1,2,3,4,5], 3))

function combinations<A>(keys: Array<A>, nb: number) {
  let combo = keys.map((_, i) => i >= keys.length - nb)

  let res = []
  do {
    res.push(filter(keys, combo))

  } while (nextPermutation(combo));
  return res
}

function nextPermutation(array: Array<boolean>, first = 0, last = array.length-1) {
  if(first>=last){
    return false;
  }
  let i = last;
  for(;;){
    const i1 = i;
    if(array[--i]<array[i1]){
      let i2 = last+1;
      while(array[i]>=array[--i2]);
      [array[i], array[i2]] = [array[i2], array[i]];
      reverse(array, i1, last);
      return true;
    }
    if(i===first){
      reverse(array, first, last);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function reverse<A>(array: Array<A>, i=0, j=array.length-1) {
  while (i < j)
    [array[i++], array[j--]] = [array[j], array[i]];
}

function filter<A>(a: Array<A>, select: Array<boolean>) {
  return a.filter((_e,i) => select[i]);
}
```